# Using xv-11 lidar

Tags: ros, lidar, xv-11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is anyone using the xv-11 lidar unit with their robot?  I am in the process of incorporating the lidar unit with my bot and would like to share information.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192852/using-xv-11-lidar/) by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have, Here's a rundown of what I've discovered.  I was never able to get GMapping to draw a good map with it.  HectorMapping did a decent job, but the maps were always slightly to big and the navigation stack never seem to work with them, my robot kept getting lost.

I ended up pulling out the tape measure and using gimp to draw a map of my house.   Using my hand drawn map the xv-11 does a real good job of keeping my robot localized, I'm please with it.

---

Originally posted by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) with karma: 258 on 2014-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-09-20**:
Have you checked if the lidar measurements are biased and show higher distances than they should?

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2014-09-20**:
They are correct when stationary, I suspect it has something to do with the 4 hz laser data and the minimum speed of my robot (0.1 m/s).  I think the neato can go much slower than that.

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2014-09-21**:
What voltage are you powering your xv-11 at?  I'm powering xv-11 at 5v and motor at 3v.  I took mine apart when I wasn't getting good results and on the power pin of the pcb board was +5v.  Something to check, also look at the firmware argument.

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2014-09-28**:
Yes, it works well with the navigation stack.

Two things to check, are you using the firmware version 2 option?
**rosrun xv_11_laser_driver neato_laser_publisher _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 _firmware_version:=2**

and what is the average rpms from the following:
**rostopic echo /rpms**

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2014-09-28**:
I found this (link below), the firmware version 1 is suppose to be powered with 3.3 volts, could be something.

[link text](http://xv11hacking.wikispaces.com/LIDAR+Sensor)

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-09-29**:
I did get the newer driver to work properly.  The rpm of the lidar unit was adjusted to 300 RPM.

**Comment by [Morpheus](https://answers.ros.org/users/779/morpheus/) on 2014-11-15**:
What did you have to change in the launch file to get a good scan?